# Confidence band around linear least-squares line (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares, confidence-interval

I am using the Matlab function `lsline` to add a linear least-squares line to a scatter plot. I would like to add a 95% confidence band around that fit line, such that it looks like this (plot is made with the python function [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html)):

[image]

However, lsline returns no fit parameters from which to construct the 95% confidence band, and the only Matlab function I could find that does return these, is `nlpredci`, but that function is used for something else (nonlinear regression prediction)

Comment: You could use [`polyfit`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) to get your regression line coefficients *and* the fit parameters.

Comment: ...and it is not forbidden to use a non-linear fit ( nlinfit ) to fit linear models...in case of emergency: Linear regression is easily programmed in a language that can handle matrices and vectors.